# Seeking books mentioned on site

Tags: sources-mekorot, zionism

On [TrueTorahJews](https://www.truetorahjews.org/) (an anti-Zionist site from a Satmar-perspective), it quotes:

"*Uvdos Vehanhagos Leveis Brisk, v. 4 p. 195*" - [source](https://www.truetorahjews.org/brisker)

And "*Mara D'ara Yisroel v. 1 p. 145*" - [source](https://www.truetorahjews.org/rebyosefchaim)

Does anyone know where to find either?

Thank you!

Comment: Check in a Sefarim store

Comment: https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/evbdvt-vhnhgvt-lbit-brisq-b-krkim.html

Comment: Thank you, so there is a possibility that those sefarim are not available online?

Comment: you may enjoy https://www.thelehrhaus.com/culture/a-controversial-halakhic-case-against-the-state-of-israel/

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, very interesting!

Comment: Are you trying to but the seforim?

Comment: I prefer online editions though

Comment: You could massively simplify your question by asking where you can find online these two specific books. The answer is to check google for the hebrew titles of the books and hebrewbooks - if they are not there, you are unlikely to find them online

Comment: I'm pretty sure עובדות והנהגות is available on Otzar Hachochmah. I'll check later.

Comment: @Harel13: Found this one: but do not know if this is the one (p. 195): https://beta.otzar.org/#/b/180646/p/-1/t/1634716687594/fs/p7hiwPyHR4hd2BLTaHxrWvNoeznEMRyR6ZRNwyBXjMkQ/start/7548/end/8362/c

Comment: It is important to keep in mind that although the website is called "Torah True Jews", many of the Hashkafos found onh the site are only a minority view, not supported by the majority of "Torah True" Gedolim.

Comment: @user29098 That widely depends on your perspective, also there are many non-Zionist and even anti-Zionist gedolim. On the flip side, those of us who are non-Zionists or anti-Zionists just admit that those Gedolim that are Zionist are just mistaken in that area but that doesn't affect their knowledge in Torah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Uvdos Vehanhagos Leveis Brisk, v. 4 p. 195

The full set is available for [purchase here](https://kulmus-books.co.il/product/%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%A7-%D7%93-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D/).

> Mara D'ara Yisroel v. 1 p. 145

This is not in print anymore. Sometimes it comes up on auction sites. You can find more [publication data](https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH001869311/NLI) on it here to assist in your hunt.

Comment: Thanks! Will be looking for the first one in a seforim store in Antwerpen. I hope they have it.